# How to add custom template link to grouped products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on woocommerce and showing listing of group products for specific category. When i am clicking on any product then it redirect to single product page which is default functionality of woocommerce. Now i want to add custom link to all group products. e.g.

http://test.com/product-title/testproduct?c=12&g=1

These parameters "C" and "G" id are coming dynamically. But when i click on this link then it redirects to product detail page. Is there a way to add custom template link to product. This is my code to get products.

```
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'washer' );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 

 echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
    endwhile; 


    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'lego-bricks' );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 
    $product_link = '';
    if($product->is_type('grouped')) {
       $product_link = site_url().'/custom-link/?c=12&g=1';
    } else {
       $product_link = get_permalink();
    }
    echo '<br /><a href="'.$product_link.'">'.
    woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.get_the_title().'</a>';
endwhile; 

wp_reset_query();
```

- Make sure your page with custom link has been assigned custom page template.

Comment: yes i have created a custom template and assigned it to a page.On product hover it is showing custom link but when i click on it then it redirects to single product page

Comment: Is there any redirect plugin or custom code in .htaccess?

Comment: No i have not installed any plugin or no code in htaccess. I am passing product name also in the url.this can be a reason but not sure?

Comment: Yes, you should not use product-title in URL.